# Non-matching values when joining input$plot_click from Shiny with original data

Tags: r, shiny

## Goal

I want to save the points that I click on a plot in a dataframe. Then I want to join this new dataframe with the original dataframe (used for creating plot).  The new columns will then be used as inputs in an algorithm to manipulate the whole data set.

## Problem

I am using `shiny`'s interactive features to achieve the above goal. However, the values that I get from `input$plot_click` have different number of significant figures from original dataframe columns. Therefore, they do not match. I'm familiar with `nearPoints()` but only for printing and don't know how I can directly filter and SAVE the original dataframe by clicking the plot.

You can run the `shiny` app and see that the `Time` column in newly created dataframe does not exactly match with the `Time` column in original dataframe `c2`. How can I get the original values by clicking?

## What I tried

Following is my code and data set for a small, reproducible example:

### Code:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)

# Global
if (!exists('c2', envir = .GlobalEnv, inherits = FALSE)) {
  print("Please load c2 dataframe")
}

## Get the unique file.ID2 from the data:
file_ID <- unique(c2$file.ID2)



# UI
ui <- fluidPage(
  
  
  titlePanel("Select Initial Changepoints in Gas Pedal Position"),
  
  
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      fluidRow(
        # Menu for selecting the file.ID2/Scenario
        selectInput("fileid", label = h3("Select scenario"), 
                    choices = file_ID)
      ),
      
      verbatimTextOutput("info"),
      
      # Button
      downloadButton("downloadData", "Download complete table")
    ),
    
    
    mainPanel(
      fluidRow(
        h4("Click plot to add points"),
        actionButton("rem_point", "Remove Last Point"),
        plotOutput("plot1", click = "plot_click",
                   hover = "plot_hover")),
      fluidRow(
        h4("Table of points on plot"),
        tableOutput("table")))
  )
)







# Server logic
server <- function(input, output) {
  
  # 1. Create data for a given file.ID2:
  ## Filter c2 according to fileid:
  data_gas <- reactive({c2 %>% 
      filter(file.ID2==input$fileid)})
  
  
  # 2. set up reactive dataframe to store data
  values <- reactiveValues()
  values$DT <- data.frame(file.ID2 = character(),
                          Time = numeric(),
                          acc_pedal_pos = numeric())
  
  
  # 3. Create the gas pedal plot 
  output$plot1 = renderPlot({
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = data_gas(),
                 aes(x = Time, y = acc_pedal_pos)) +
      geom_point(data  = values$DT,
                 aes(x = Time, y = acc_pedal_pos, color = file.ID2), size = 2) 
  })
  
  
  # 4. add new row to reactive dataframe upon clicking plot 
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    # each input is a factor so levels are consistent for plotting characteristics
    add_row <- data.frame(file.ID2 = input$fileid,
                          Time = input$plot_click$x,
                          acc_pedal_pos = input$plot_click$y)
    # add row to the data.frame
    values$DT <- rbind(values$DT, add_row)
  })
  
  # 5. remove row on actionButton click 
  observeEvent(input$rem_point, {
    rem_row <- values$DT[-nrow(values$DT), ]
    values$DT <- rem_row
  })
  
  # 6. render a table of the growing dataframe 
  output$table <- renderTable({
    values$DT
  })
  
  
  
  # 
  output$info <- renderPrint({
    nearPoints(data_gas()[,c("file.ID2","Time", "acc_pedal_pos")], 
               input$plot_hover, threshold = 1)
  })
  
  
  
  
  # 7. Downloadable csv of selected dataset ----
  output$downloadData <- downloadHandler(
    filename = function() {
      paste("gas_pedal_CP_data", ".csv", sep = "")
    },
    content = function(file) {
      write.csv(values$DT, file, row.names = FALSE)
    }
  )
  
  
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

### Data

```
> dput(c2)
structure(list(file.ID2 = c("Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", "Cars_02", 
"Cars_02", "Cars_02"), Time = c(96.05, 96.0666666666667, 96.0833333333333, 
96.1, 96.1166666666667, 96.1333333333333, 96.15, 96.1666666666667, 
96.1833333333333, 96.2, 96.2166666666667, 96.2333333333333, 96.25, 
96.2666666666667, 96.2833333333333, 96.3, 96.3166666666667, 96.3333333333333, 
96.35, 96.3666666666667, 96.3833333333333, 96.4, 96.4166666666667, 
96.4333333333333, 96.45, 96.4666666666667, 96.4833333333333, 
96.5, 96.5166666666667, 96.5333333333333, 96.55, 96.5666666666667, 
96.5833333333333, 96.6, 96.6166666666667, 96.6333333333333, 96.65, 
96.6666666666667, 96.6833333333333, 96.7, 96.7166666666667, 96.7333333333333, 
96.75, 96.7666666666667, 96.7833333333333, 96.8, 96.8166666666667, 
96.8333333333333, 96.85, 96.8666666666667, 96.8833333333333, 
96.9, 96.9166666666667, 96.9333333333333, 96.95, 96.9666666666667, 
96.9833333333333, 97, 97.0166666666667, 97.0333333333333, 97.05, 
97.0666666666667, 97.0833333333333, 97.1, 97.1166666666667, 97.1333333333333, 
97.15, 97.1666666666667, 97.1833333333333, 97.2, 97.2166666666667, 
97.2333333333333, 97.25, 97.2666666666667, 97.2833333333333, 
97.3, 97.3166666666667, 97.3333333333333, 97.35, 97.3666666666667, 
97.3833333333333, 97.4, 97.4166666666667, 97.4333333333333, 97.45, 
97.4666666666667, 97.4833333333333, 97.5, 97.5166666666667, 97.5333333333333, 
97.55, 97.5666666666667, 97.5833333333333, 97.6, 97.6166666666667, 
97.6333333333333, 97.65, 97.6666666666667, 97.6833333333333, 
97.7, 97.7166666666667), acc_pedal_pos = c(0.143937006592751, 
0.145196855068207, 0.146771654486656, 0.14866141974926, 0.150236219167709, 
0.154960632324219, 0.155590549111366, 0.154960632324219, 0.155275583267212, 
0.155275583267212, 0.155275583267212, 0.155905514955521, 0.157165348529816, 
0.156850397586823, 0.156535431742668, 0.156535431742668, 0.15748031437397, 
0.156850397586823, 0.155905514955521, 0.155590549111366, 0.154015749692917, 
0.152125984430313, 0.148976370692253, 0.146771654486656, 0.143307089805603, 
0.140157476067543, 0.135748028755188, 0.131023615598679, 0.124409452080727, 
0.115590550005436, 0.104251965880394, 0.0881889760494232, 0.0636220499873161, 
0.0349606312811375, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 
0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0.025826770812273, 0.0343307070434093, 0.0450393706560135, 
0.0566929131746292, 0.0667716562747955, 0.0740157514810562, 0.0762204751372337, 
0.0771653577685356, 0.0765354335308075, 0.0771653577685356, 0.0762204751372337, 
0.0781102329492569, 0.0796850398182869, 0.0840944871306419, 0.0897637829184532, 
0.0973228365182877, 0.106456689536572, 0.116220474243164, 0.125669285655022, 
0.135748028755188, 0.143622040748596, 0.149291336536407, 0.152755901217461, 
0.155905514955521, 0.154960632324219, 0.155590549111366, 0.154645666480064, 
0.154015749692917, 0.154330715537071, 0.154960632324219, 0.154960632324219, 
0.155275583267212, 0.155590549111366, 0.154645666480064, 0.154645666480064, 
0.153385832905769, 0.154645666480064, 0.154330715537071, 0.154015749692917, 
0.154645666480064, 0.154960632324219, 0.154330715537071, 0.154645666480064, 
0.154645666480064, 0.154330715537071, 0.154645666480064)), .Names = c("file.ID2", 
"Time", "acc_pedal_pos"), row.names = c(NA, -101L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess something like that should work:

```
  observeEvent(input$plot_click, {
    # each input is a factor so levels are consistent for plotting characteristics

    add_row <- data.frame(file.ID2 = input$fileid,
                          Time = c2 %>% 
                            filter(file.ID2==input$fileid) %>%
                            mutate(diff = Time - input$plot_click$x) %>%
                            filter(diff == min(abs(diff))) %>%
                            select(Time),
                          acc_pedal_pos =c2 %>% 
                            filter(file.ID2==input$fileid) %>%
                            mutate(diff = Time - input$plot_click$x) %>%
                            filter(diff == min(abs(diff))) %>%
                            select(acc_pedal_pos))
    # add row to the data.frame
    values$DT <- rbind(values$DT, add_row)
  })
```

Here I select the point with the closest time to the point selected by creating the column diff `mutate(diff = Time - input$plot_click$x)` and filter for the diff value the closest to zero `filter(diff == min(abs(diff)))`. You can then assign the value of time and acc_pedal_pos by selecting the proper column `select(acc_pedal_pos))`

Comment: Thanks. This works. But I was wondering if there is a more elegant solution in the lines of `rbind`ing the data frame from `nearPoints` and saving that.

Comment: truth is I don't know, I am discovering shiny with your example (which is nice by the way)